# # R subset only one or two characters BEFORE pattern separately?

Tags: r, subset, extract

I would like to subset one or two word before pattern from column using **rematches** and **gregexpr** or **sub.**

```
state<-regmatches(data[,2], gregexpr(???  , data[,2])) # California
type<-regmatches(data[,2], gregexpr( ??? , data[,2])) # Valencia
```

This is a sample sentence, and I failed to extract previous words separately.

```
sample<-" 2018 summer California Valencia orange"
sub("[O|o]range.*","",sample)
[1] " 2018 summer California Valencia "
```

How can I subset one character before a pattern, and two previous character before pattern?

Comment: can you show the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use regex lookaround to extract the word (`\\w+`) before the space (`\\s*`) and 'orange' substring

```
regmatches(sample, regexpr("(\\w+)(?=\\s*[Oo]range)", sample, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "Valencia"
```

In the second case, change the lookaround to include a word and space before the 'orange'

```
regmatches(sample, regexpr("(\\w+)(?=\\s*\\w+\\s*[Oo]range)", sample, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "California"
```

Comment: if I want to subet AFTER the space, what is the code? Like I want to subset one or two words after summer  in order to extract  Califorina and Valencia. Thank you so much.

Comment: @rocknRrr Try `regmatches(sample, regexpr("(?<=summer )(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)", sample, perl = TRUE))#
[1] "California Valencia"`